# Recursively initialise std::array using metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have to initialize a `std::array<my_vector, N>`, `my_vector` being a `std::vector` with a custom allocator. The way I did it is:

1. Allocated `N` memory pools
2. Created a `std::array` of `allocator`, that each have their memory pool
3. Created a `std::array` of `std::vector`, that each have their allocator.

The simplified code looks like this:

```cpp
std::array<std::array<char, POOL_SIZE>, N> memory_pools;

std::array<allocator<POOL_SIZE>, N> allocators{
    std::get<0>(memory_pools),
    std::get<1>(memory_pools),
    std::get<2>(memory_pools),
    //...
    std::get<N-1>(memory_pools),
};

using my_vector = std::vector<my_class, my_allocator>;

std::array<my_vector, N> vectors{
    my_vector{std::get<0>(allocators)},
    my_vector{std::get<1>(allocators)},
    my_vector{std::get<2>(allocators)},
    //...
    my_vector{std::get<N-1>(allocators)},
}
```

This works, *however*, this is quite verbose, given that my constant `N` is over 100, and writing all this by hand produces bloated code, and when I change N, I have to write this whole section again.

#### Question: Is there any way to make the compiler write the initialisation for me ?

What I want to do is

```cpp
std::array<allocator<POOL_SIZE>, N> allocators =
make_array_from_pool<POOL_SIZE, N>(memory_pools);

std::array<my_vector, N> vectors = 
make_array_from_allocators<N>(allocators);
```

I've already tried to do some recursive templated function, inside a nested class, but I'm confronted with conversion error.

This is roughly what I was trying:

```cpp
template<size_t POOL_SIZE, size_t N, size_t ORDER> 
class ArrayMaker{
    static std::array<allocator<POOL_SIZE>, ORDER> from_pool(
    std::array<std::array<char, POOL_SIZE>, N>
    memory_pool
){
    return {
        ArrayMaker<POOL_SIZE, N, ORDER-1>::from_pool(memory_pool),
        std::get<ORDER-1>(memory_pool)
    };
}
};

template<size_t POOL_SIZE, size_t N> 
class ArrayMaker<POOL_SIZE, N, 1>{
    static std::array<allocator<POOL_SIZE>, 1> from_pool(
    std::array<std::array<char, POOL_SIZE>, N>
    memory_pool
){
    return {std::get<0>(memory_pool)};
}
};

template<size_t POOL_SIZE, size_t N> 
static std::array<allocator<POOL_SIZE>, N> make_array_from_pool(
    std::array<std::array<char, POOL_SIZE>, N>
    memory_pool
){
    return ArrayMaker<POOL_SIZE,N, N>::from_pool(memory_pool);
}
```

The error I get is `could not convert ... from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::array<allocator<POOL_SIZE>, 2>'`

It's my understanding that it is because std::array only supports aggregate initialisation.

Comment: Any restrictions on C++ version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any recursion to achieve this, you can simply use `std::index_sequence`. E.g.

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
void init_arrays_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    static constexpr auto N = sizeof...(Is);

    std::array<std::array<char, POOL_SIZE>, N> memory_pools;

    std::array<allocator<POOL_SIZE>, N> allocators{
        std::get<Is>(memory_pools)...
    };

    using my_vector = std::vector<my_class, my_allocator>;

    std::array<my_vector, N> vectors{
        my_vector{std::get<Is>(allocators)}...
    };
}

template <std::size_t N>
void init_arrays()
{
    init_arrays_impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/BRVSlm)

Comment: Wow, that is super clean. Thank you, I'll try that ! Quick question: in this demo, I guess the `std::array` would fall out of scope as soon as `init_arrays_impl` completes.

What would be the recommended way to proceed for class member `std::array` ? Create functions that return `std::array` and hope copy-elision will work its magic, or _pass_ my `allocators` and `vectors` variables as parameters to `init_arrays_impl` ?

Comment: @NebularNoise: use a function that returns an array. RVO will very likely take place. In C++17 copy elision is mandatory.